# Create a Trigger to fire on all Tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

i have a table named "LogDelete" to save information about users that deleted any rows on any tables. the table fields are like this :

```
create table LogDelete
(
    pk int identity(1,1) primary key,
    TableName varchar(15),
    DeleteUser nvarchar(20),
    DeleteDate datetime
)
```

Actually i wanna create a trigger that fire on all tables on update action that on every update write proper information on LogDelete Table,
at now i use a stored procedure and call it on every update action on my tables.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Do your all tables have one-column-int PK? If yes, I do have a solution that may help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There are 'event' triggers, but they are mainly related to loggin in. These kinds of triggers are actually DDL triggers, so they are not related to updating data, but to updating your database scheme.

Afaik, there is no trigger that fires on every update. That means that the way you are handling it now, through a stored procedure, is probably the best way. You can create triggers on each table to call the procedure and do the logging.

You might even write a script that creates all those triggers for you in one run. That will make the initial creating and later updating of the triggers a bit easier.

Here is some [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx), which says (in remarks about DML triggers):

> CREATE TRIGGER must be the first statement in the batch and **can apply to only one table**.

Comment: thank you, could you please write it's script? i don't know how to create a script to run once for all tables.

Answer (score 0):

There is no magic solution for your request, not such a thing as `event triggers` to all `DML` (`INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`) as you like, but there are some alternatives that you can consider:

1. If you are using SQL Server 2008 or after, the best thing you could use is `CDC` (`Change Data Capture`), you can start with [this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/introduction-to-change-data-capture-%28cdc%29-in-sql-server-2008/) by Dave Pinal, I think this will be the best approach since it is not affected by any change in structures.
2. Read the log file. You'll need analyze it find each DML activity in the log and so you could build an unified operation to log the changes that you need, obviously this is not on-line and not trivial
3. Same as option two but using traces on all the DML activities. The advantage of this approach is that it can be almost online and it will not require analyzing the log file, you'll just need to analyze a profiler table.